# How to "lock" From email address to 1 address depending on case record type

Tags: email, email2case

Could you please advise if there is a way to "lock" From on Send an Email page related to a case record.

I have multiple email2case instances setup in SF. When case is created from an incoming email, it is created with a certain case record type.

I want to prevent other users selecting wrong From email address when they are replying to emails related to a case.

Is it possible to do this with going into apex coding?

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has released a feature in the Spring 15 release in which you can use custom logic in Apex classes to specify the email fields so that they make sense for your business content.

You create templates for specific criteria with a default "From" field.

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_case_feed_default_email_fields.htm